# Host name alias resolves to different computer in network

Tags: domain-name-system, alias

I have an alias 'DATA-SERVER' for many machines in my network. When I try to access DATA-SERVER from a computer (say Computer A), it resolves to some other Computer C and not to A itself. How do I possibly resolve this?

To add the host alias, I modified the Lanmanserver Parameters in the registry by adding 'DATA-SERVER' in Optional Names key.

{I need to have the alias on multiple machines for my program to reroute to the same machine. The alias is hard coded in the program and I can't modify it}

> SOLVED : The solution was to add the following entry to the hosts file on the
>   machine
>
> > 127.0.0.1 'DATA-SERVER'

Comment: Where did this alias that you have come from?

Comment: This alias was hard coded. So, I modified the registry in the computer to add alias to the host. It worked perfectly when this was done for only one machine in the network. But after doing this in multiple machines, it is resolving to a different machine and not to localhost

Comment: What do you mean? Exactly what change did you make to the registry? In addition you should provide any other relevant details, even if you haven't been asked for them.

Comment: There you go. I've edited the question

Comment: Am I correct to assume that this is about active directory rather than dns per se?